# How do I make a command line program using click in python that takes separates command parameters that run different scripts?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I have the following code:

```
import click

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@click.command()
def initdb():
    click.echo('Initialized the database')

@click.command()
def dropdb():
    click.echo('Dropped the database')

cli.add_command(initdb)
cli.add_command(dropdb)
```

At the command line I want to be able to do something like the following:

```
python clicktest.py cli initdb
```

and have the following happen echo at the terminal:

```
Initialized the database
```

Or to enter into the terminal:

```
python clicktest.py cli dropdb
```

and have the following happen on the terminal:

```
Dropped the database
```

My problem is currently when I do this at the terminal:

```
 python clicktest.py cli initdb
```

Nothing happens at the terminal, nothing prints when I think something should, namely the 'Initialized Database' echo. What am i doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use it in command line like:

```
python clicktest.py initdb
python clicktest.py dropdb
```

And in your `clicktest.py` file, place these lines at the bottom of your code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

Unless, your code won't get work.

EDIT:

If you really want to use it in a way `python clicktest.py cli initdb`, then you have another choice:

```
@click.group()
def main():
    pass

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@click.command()
def initdb():
    click.echo('Initialized the database')

@click.command()
def dropdb():
    click.echo('Dropped the database')

cli.add_command(initdb)
cli.add_command(dropdb)
main.add_command(cli)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Or even better (Using decorators instead):

```
@click.group()
def main():
    pass

@main.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command()
def initdb():
    click.echo('Initialized the database')

@cli.command()
def dropdb():
    click.echo('Dropped the database')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```